# Logging in a Weblogic Clustered Environment -LINUX

Tags: java, linux, log4j, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a Application consiting oj JSP, Servlets and cosumes Webservices.I am using lo4j.propetties to log the events.This application is deployed on Weblogic on a Cluster consisting of 2 server on two different Machine.The content of which are

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CA1, FA1

log4j.appender.FA1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FA1.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FA1.File=ABC.log 
log4j.appender.FA1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] - %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.CA1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.CA1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.CA1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] - %c - %m%n
```

The location where these log files are created are

/u01/CRM/domains/e09/domain_CRM/ABC.log and

/u01/CRM/domains/e10/domain_CRM/ABC.log

Since my server are on different machine, I therefore need a centralized loogign Place something like this

/u01/CRM/logs/server1/ABC.log

/u01/CRM/logs/server2/ABC.log

How do I do that

Answer (score 2):

Relying on a [SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) is the common approach in a clustered enviroment. You'll need an additional log4j server, that will aggregate all your log messages into a shared file. Check out these SO discussions for details:

- [Log4j in a clustered enviroment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901970/log4j-in-clustered-environment)
- [How to use a SocketAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender)

Comment: No No...i cannot have a extra server.we are only a week for go live...all i can do is to do some changes at code level..

Comment: Another option is to use a network file system and to write your logs into a shared directory (see restrictions from the first link). You can also keep them in a database or use JMS.