# Log file is not getting generated at a desired location

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to generate log file at a location using Java code, but it is not getting generated where it should get generated.

Snippet:

```java
static {
    try {
        System.setProperty("logFilePath", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/app.log");
        configLevelData = HelperMethods.getGlobalVarsFromConfig(configFilePath);
        log = LogManager.getLogger(Runner.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="LogToFile"
                     fileName="${logFilePath}"
                     filePattern="{DEFAULT}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.vodafone.tv.runner" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.vodafone.tv.utils.CollectFiles" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: add full log4j file content

Comment: check now added

Comment: Use `${sys:logFilePath}` instead of `${logFilePath}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use system properties OR variables in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332525/use-system-properties-or-variables-in-log4j)