# log4j2 logfile location, one for local Eclipse Dev one during deploy

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 and have a rolling file configured in log4j2.xml as

```
<RollingFile name="a2.log" append="true"
   fileName="C:/Dev/error_log/local_error_log_app_name.log" 
   filePattern="C:/Dev/error_log/local_error_log_app_name_-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz">
```

This is good for local Eclipse Development but when I deploy to a JBOSS server I'd like the path and filename to be appropriate for that file system, without having to remember to edit the log4j2.xml file before deploying.

`fileName="/www/logs/error_log/error_log_app_name.log"`

I've seen the following posts

[How to give dynamic file name in the appender in log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810926/how-to-give-dynamic-file-name-in-the-appender-in-log4j-xml)

[Log4J2 - assigning file appender filename at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862770/log4j2-assigning-file-appender-filename-at-runtime)

and tried 
`fileName="$${sys:logFilename}"` and `fileName="${sys:logFilename}"` but all that did was put a file `${sys` in the Jboss bin folder `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring a property in your config file?
The log4j2 docs have an example here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

If this does not work, please raise a ticket in the log4j2 issue tracker:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: Yes right after my post I realized you can declare a property in the log4j.xml.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a property in log4j2.xml, use double dollar signs $$

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="filenameVariable">$${sys:errorLogFileName}</Property>
    <Property name="filePatternVariable">$${sys:errorLogFilePattern}</Property>
</Properties>
```

and reference using single dollar sign $

```
<RollingFile name="a2.log" append="true"
    fileName="${filename}" 
filePattern="${filePattern}">
```

However it is not necessary to use a property.  Just reference the system property directly, again with just single dollar sign

```
<RollingFile name="a2.log" append="true"
    fileName="${sys:errorLogFileName}" 
filePattern="${sys:errorLogFilePattern}">
```

And to the answer to my actual issue how to dynamically specify log file based on whether I am running locally in Eclipse or deployed to our server, I'm using

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

@PostConstruct
private void startup() {

       if (File("C:/").exists()) {
         System.setProperty("errorLogFileName", "C:/path/to/error_log.txt");
         System.setProperty("errorLogFilePattern", "C:/path/to/error_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz");
       } else {
         System.setProperty("errorLogFileName", "/unix/path/to/error_log.txt");
         System.setProperty("errorLogFilePattern", "/unix/path/to/error_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz");
      }
}
}
```

**Important!** Without a system property set `System.setProperty("whatever")` the lookup in your log4j2.xml will fail and instead log4j will write to a file named as the first part of your lookup before the semicolon i.e. `${sys`