# how to put system properties variables in the layout of log4j?

Tags: log4j

I am trying to display one of my system properties in my app, so far I have

```
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}[${tag_name}]:%-5p [%t]%c %x - %m%n
```

Where `${tag_name}` is the system properties variable. I want to see in my log statements. Is this the right format?

Comment: Try looking into log4j source code and understand if system properties are allowed in layout

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810926/how-to-give-dynamic-file-name-in-the-appender-in-log4j-xml