# how to write logged in user specific logs in hadoop using log4j

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hadoop2

Using Log4j iam trying to write logged in user level logs.

suppose using 'X' user i logged in to a machine, i need to get the user name in Log4J properties file. So, i can write my logs to : /Desktop/X/final.log
similarly, if Y user then it should write to : /Desktop/Y/final.log

i tried using ${user} but not working.

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.File=/Desktop/${user}/final.log

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this is by injecting a system property in the program that uses `log4j`. For example if you're running some java program you can pass in the `user` property with `-Duser=<your_user>`.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/Desktop/${user}/final.log
```

Even better, you could parametrize the whole log filename if you want. There's a similar question with a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810926/how-to-give-dynamic-file-name-in-the-appender-in-log4j-xml).