# How to read .properties file in a log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, properties, log4j2

I want to use a .properties files's value in a log4j2.xml file.

But log4j2.xml cant use bean element, the follow way is wrong

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Is there any way to load a .properties file in a log4j.xml?

Comment: Are you initializing log4j2 with spring? If not then it wont be available.

Comment: Here is how you could use placeholders in log4.xml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810926/how-to-give-dynamic-file-name-in-the-appender-in-log4j-xml

Comment: @SMA  Should I init log4j2 explicitly？

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy   I've tried use jvm param and add System.setProperty, but they don't work. I'll check my code again

Comment: @lulijun did you find solution for this?

Comment: @krishna_5c3 Not yet