# log4j2 Dynamic log file name in Java

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have simple question.

How to have log file name dynamically supplied from code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${logfilename}.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Here file name is **logs/app.log**.

- How to make it dynamic with date and time appended as well in file name? Though pattern is applied but it doesn't work.
- Here **logs** is the directory which log4j library automatically creates, can it be dynamic as well?

**EDIT** In parameter `fileName` I have placed `${logfilename}.log` and setting system property as below:

```
System.setProperty("logfilename", "a_cool_logname");
```

Now it is creating file with name `${logfilename}.log` which is definitely not required.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give dynamic file name in the appender in log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810926/how-to-give-dynamic-file-name-in-the-appender-in-log4j-xml)

Comment: This line `System.setProperty("logfilename", "a_cool_logname");` creates log file with name `${logfilename}.log`. Funny though :D

Comment: See the [log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#separate_log_files)

Answer (score 0):

**Property File Look like this **

```
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FA


#Console Appender WE WRE NOT USING IT
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MM yy HH:mm} %-5p  %m%n


#File Appender
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File=${fName}
#log4j.appender.FA.MaxFileSize=5MB
#log4j.appender.FA.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MM yy HH:mm} %8p  %10m%n 

# Set the logger level of File Appender to WARN
log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = DEBUG
```

**And set Properties in JAVA  **

```
System.setProperty("fName", "d:\\siemens\\" + getDateTime() + c.getSimpleName() +".log");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

*let me know if u need further query  thanks*

Comment: I am using `log4j2` library. It can have configuration file in **xml**.